# StringExpression: Cleaning up curated datasets from camel-case for CSV export

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset, curated-data

## Context:

If a `Property` of a Wolfram Curated Dataset could contain multiple elements, it is stored as a `List`; further, although these elements are stored as `String`s, Wolfram uses condensed camel-case.

Together these features may pose a few problems; namely, a `Dataset` with an element with the `Head` `List` can not be exported to CSV and depending on later usage, one may find camel-case unappealing.

Thus the question arises how to efficiently solve these two minor hurdles, without having to map camel-case to regular case with spaces (which, if the `Dataset` includes acronyms, may seem challenging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Getting the data**

For example purposes, lets use the curated `GeneomeData` dataset. In regards to processing a `List` element in a `Dataset` as well as camel-case, we will focus on the `Property` `"BiologicalProcesses"`. Perhaps one may be interested in retrieving the name, nucleotide sequence and relevant biological processes data for those genes in the dataset:

```
genes = GenomeData[];
ntSeq = Table[GenomeData[genes[[g]]],{g, Length@genes}];
bioPr = Table[GenomeData[genes[[g]], "BiologicalProcesses"],{g, Length@genes}];
```

converting the results into a smaller `Dataset`:

```
headers = {"Gene Names", "Nucleotide Sequence", "Biological Processes"};
columns = {genes, ntSeq, bioPr};
data = Dataset@Map[AssociationThread[headers, #] &]@Transpose[columns];
```

for convenience we'll just delete those rows which are incomplete:

```
data = DeleteMissing[data, 1, 1]
```

Now that we have some cleaned data, we can focus on camel-case and the list issue.

**Camel-case**

Within the first 20 records of our dataset we can see some interesting cases for string processing such as:

- "PlasmaMembraneOrganizationAndBiogenesis"
- "TRNAAminoacylation"

To remove camel-case from the first one is actually fairly straight forward. We wish to find a string [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html?q=Pattern) - called a [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) - where there is a lowercase character followed by an uppercase character, and then add a space between them:

```
spaceBetweenWords = StringReplace[(x_?LowerCaseQ ~~ y_?UpperCaseQ) -> x ~~ " " ~~ y];
```

The second may seem more daunting, as how can a string pattern recognize an acronym? Well,since every new work in camel-case starts with a capital character, the problem is quite simple. We just look for three characters: an uppercase, followed by an uppercase, followed by a lowercase. We then insert a space between the two uppercase characters:

```
spaceForAcronyms = 
  StringReplace[(x_?UpperCaseQ ~~ y_?UpperCaseQ ~~ z_?LowerCaseQ) -> 
    x ~~ " " ~~ y ~~ z];
```

This will solve *most* camel-case issues (at least in this list). There is a notable except within the first 20 records as well:

- `"ProteinAminoAcidOLinkedGlycosylation"`

which should technically have a hyphen to be "Protein Amino Acid O-Linked Glycosylation"; however "Protein Amino Acid O Linked Glycosylation" is equally readable and results from the above two transformations.

**Handling Lists**

In this case we have a list of strings. If we wanted to make the list similar to a csv (but only take up one cell), we could [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html?q=Riffle) commas (or whatever delimiter you want) between the entries and join them to a single string:

```
listOfStringsToCSV[list_List]:= Module[
                                {length = Length@list},
                                If[length > 1, 
                                  StringJoin@Riffle[list,{", "}],
                                  First@list] 
                                ]
```

Since, in this case, we also wish to perform the string transformations, we can include them here:

```
listOfStringsToCSV[list_List]:= Module[
                                {length = Length@list},
                                If[length > 1, 
                                  spaceForAcronyms@spaceBetweenWords@StringJoin@Riffle[list,{", "}],
                                  First@spaceForAcronyms@spaceBetweenWords@list] 
                                ]
```

note: that doing so kind of goes against the wolfram / functional programming practice of one function doing one thing and then building upon a series of function calls.

addendum: should one wish to then lowercase all but the first word, one can make a similar [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) looking for a space, capital and then lowercase (to ensure it is not an acronym) and apply it last.

**Wrapping up**

All that is left to do is apply this function to the appropriate column in our dataset:

```
processedData = data[All, {"Biological Processes" -> (listOfStringsToCSV)}]
```

[image]